# Fundamental question related to basic sine or cosine function

Tags: trigonometry

Given the most basic sine or cosine:

$y=sin(x)$, where  $x$ is a variable in radians.

Since it is known that their period os $T=2\pi$, then their frequency is $f=1/T=1/(2\pi)$.

This seems rather confusing because we can see on the wavy graph and on the trig circle that it completes 1 full cycle in 2pi angular period. However intuitively we rather think that the "abstract or angular frequency " (dont know how to call it) should be 1. But it is $1/(2\pi)$ since freq is inverse of period.

Of course if we use the usual formula:
$y=sin(2\pi f x)$

Then we can use f=1 and if try to compute as before we get f=$2\pi/2\pi =1$. Then we can interpret $x$ as time (in seconds) so we can talk about freq. in Hz, as is often the case in physics, for example $x \in [0,1]$ between 0 and 1 sec. Then plotting thisin e.g. Matlab displays the correct nb of oscillations as given by f.

My question is what interpretation to give to this $1/2\pi$ frequency for a most basic wave sin(x), as developed in the beginning of my question.

Comment: You already gave the answer: "Since it is known that their period os $T=2\pi$, then their frequency is $f=1/T=1/(2\pi)$." This is crystal clear.

Comment: Well you didnt get my question : its more like an intuitive question... ok mechanicaly yes it is 1/2pi but read agzin my post... it is strange to think of it as a fractionnal frequency  dont you think ?2pi is a full cycle

Comment: You did't get my answer. This is a site about mathematics.

Comment: There must be a way to put words around that. I will wait for someone who can. I am not talking about just applying blindly a formula (I know it may seem a bit fundamental but nevertheless one should be able to reformulate it i guess)

Comment: If you have a frequency in Hertz (cycles per second) for something that happens only once a minute, the frequency is $1/60$. What is confusing about that? Likewise something that happens only once every $2\pi$ distance along the $x$ axis, the frequency (in cycles per unit of $x$ increase) is $1/(2\pi).$

Comment: hum yes... said like that it sounds better , once every 2pi... yes sorry i don't know why suddenly it seems strange not to have a freq of 1 cycle for a simple wave sin(x)... usually to avoid any problems i always write sin(2pift) and use t in seconds and my f in hz (s^-1)

Comment: But is it strange to say something happends $2\pi$ times every $2\pi$ hence the ordinary frequency of "1"?

Comment: Frequency without time seems a strange concept anyway. Your formula $\sin(2\pi ft)$ with $t$ in seconds and $f$ in Hz makes more physical sense. The period is still useful even without time because you can generate the entire function by making copies of the interval $[0,T]$. If you had a much longer interval, say $[0,1000],$ and wanted to know approximately how many copies of the wave $\sin(x)$ fit in that interval, multiplying by $f=1/(2\pi)$ might make sense, but dividing by $2\pi$ seems more intuitive to me.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that in physics, $Hz$ is not a fundamental unit, it is simply an abbreviation for "per second." A frequency is similarly a measure of how many complete waveforms happen after a unit time. (Which, in standards units would be 1 second)

$\sin(x)$ is the same. The input isn't describing a physical quantity anymore, but the question is still, "how many complete waveforms happen in the space between the inputs $x$ to $x+1$?" You can see from the graph it's less than one, but how much less? It's the amount such that when you multiply it by $2 \pi$ (because you're adding $2 \pi$ units of input together for a single period) you get $1$ waveform. And that amount is $\frac{1}{2\pi}$.

Comment: i dont understand : "You can see from the graph it's less than one, but how much less? " from a graph between 0 and 2 pi I see 1 cycle. The question really is why do we consider sin(x) to have frequency 1/2pi - other than the fact we are mechanically applying 1/T , knowing that T=2pi (the latter is clear)

Comment: You can see from that graph that you don't have a complete cycle between 0 and **1**, not all the way up to $2 \pi$, right? By the time you get to $1$, you've gone part of the way up, but not at all down again.

Comment: oh yes sure because with sin(x) x=1 is 1 radian or about 57 degrees so far from the full cycle yes

Comment: The fraction of the full cycle that 1 radian takes up is the frequency.

Comment: yes i know that it was that it seems suddenly strange to not have a f=1 for a sin(x) but its true that i am probably complicating things and as another said since tje period is 2pi the frequency is 1 cycle per 2pi so i guss i can accept that it is 1/2pi